# How to reformat long line of array in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, eslint, prettier

I have a long list of the array defined in the JavaScript file as follows:

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', ..................]
```

The length of the line is more than 80 character. I tried to reformat the code using the `Code | Reformat code` menu item, but the formatter didn't split the code into multiple lines.

What I expect is reformatted change the code to the following.

```
const array = [
    'a',
    'b', 
    'c',
    ...
  ];
```

How could I do it?

Comment: Check various settings under `Preferences > Editor > Code Style > JavaScript > Wrappings and Braces`

Answer (score 2):

in **Preferences > Editor > Code Style > JavaScript > Wrappings and Braces**, set **Arrays** to **Wrap if long** (or **Chop down if long**) and set **Hard wrap at** value to `80`